# MySQL InnoDB table with a Hash Index

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash

I have a table like this.

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Later i have created a HASH index like this.

```
CREATE INDEX index ON table (column) USING HASH;
```

Latter i have try some explain queries.

Like

```
explain Select * from table where column=132;
```

And i see the engine is using the index on possible_keys and in the key stuff says the name of the index!!

But in the docs says that InnoDB doesn't allow hash index now i wonder why my innoDB Supposedly allows the hash index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InnoDB silently changes "HASH" into "BTree".  A BTree index does what a HASH does, plus more.  Or do you think there is some good reason to want Hash?

"Good reason" -- MySQL was created many years ago.  It was designed to be 'lean and mean'.  Many features were boiled down to "one size fits all":  BTree for indexing; Nested Loop Join for `JOINing`, etc.

Meanwhile, for future expansion and pseudo compatibility, some common syntax variants were included -- `HASH` for indexing, `DESC` for index ordering, etc.  Even though those "lie" about what will happen, the database engine still gives you the 'right' answer.

Over time, the most glaring shortcuts have been remedied.

- Replication (3.xx?)
- Transactions (Adding InnoDB in 4.0) (MyISAM had `LOCK TABLES`, but that was not really adequate.)
- `information_schema` (4.1?)  (versus a variety of `SHOW` commands)  Note:  8.0 overhauled it with the "data dictionary")
- Character sets and collations (4.1) (vs "latin_swedish_ci", which was good enough for the implementor.)
- Stored routines (vs client code) (5.0)
- Subqueries (`TEMPORARY TABLEs` were not adequate)
- Various `JOIN` optimizations  (5.6, 5,7, 8.0)
- `only_full_group_by` (MariaDB 10.1?, 5.7)
- `ALTER` not 'always' copying the table over (mostly 5.7)
- "Generated" columns (5.7)
- "Tablespaces" (5.7)
- JSON datatype and functions
- `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` indexing in InnoDB (5.7, 8.0) (so MyISAM can be deprecated)
- `DESC` in `INDEXes` (8.0) (*very* few use cases really need this)
- "Windowing" functions  (MariaDB 10.2, then MySQL 8.0)
- CTEs (MariaDB 10.2, then MySQL 8.0)
- Security:  Better password handling (4.1?, 5.6, 8.0)
- HA (High Availability) (MariaDB with Galera; 8.0 with InnoDB Cluster)
- At-rest encryption (8.0?)

Notice how the list is somewhat ordered from "must have" to "nice to have".  Yet to come *may* include

- Multi-threaded execution (Useless if you are I/O-bound anyway) (a very few use cases in 8.0)
- `HASH` indexing (and other types) (MariaDB 10.4, only for `UNIQUE` on `TEXT/BLOB`)
- Global `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` for `PARTITIONing`.  (Not that partitioning is very useful.)
- More syntax compatibility with standards and other vendors (MariaDB already does a much better job of this)

Meanwhile, some things are going away (or have already gone away -- either in MariaDB or MySQL)

- Compiling for a large variety of computers -- such as Atari
- The Query Cache -- Handy for benchmarking, but not really useful in Production environments.  And a major hassle to implement in any 'cluster' topology.
- MyISAM has major deficiencies relative to InnoDB, and has very few benefits.  (Arguably, the only benefit is less disk space needed.)

Comment: well a hash is about specific keys without any ordering, so the insert won't force the system to reorder the btree. If i always know what I want and my primary operation is "give the thing with id xyz" a hash index should have O(1) vs O(log n).

Hash indexes aren't built for range operations so the downside is there as well still, there are many good reasons to want a hash over a btree and otherwise.

Comment: @shadowdroid - BTrees sometimes need to juggle blocks; Hashes sometimes need to build a 'chain'.  For a _billion_ rows, O(log n) is about 5.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It doesn't change the fact that sometimes a hash index is a total valid choice. esp if I don't have ranges for example if I store encrypted data as key for something linke onetime links a BTREE is kinda useless. 

Still in most cases in SQL we want to select ranges so a BTREE to me is the better choice for most applications. I was going for the "good reason". There can be good reasons, that's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @shadowdroid - I added to my Answer to elaborate on "good reason".

Answer (score 5):

The feature in InnoDB is called *Adaptive Hash Index*,

Whether to use hash index depends on the scale of the table and query frequency, it's a completely internal strategy and normally out of configuration.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html

Comment: Yes.  That feature is used internally _if_ it is deemed useful _and_ the data will fit in an in-memory hash.  That is, it is limited it in size, whereas regular indexes are virtually unlimited in size.

Comment: And `slave_rows_search_algorithms` can include `HASH_SCAN`, but I know nothing about that.